# What is responsible for refraction flickering and how can it be improved?

Tags: three.js

[image: flickering of refraction]

My refracted objects flicker as the object rotates. When zoomed in, the effect is rarer, but still present.

My refraction is achieved with a simple `transmission:1, thickness:0.2`.

Is there some sort of a setting/map I can increase that would help it?

**Edit:** [Here's a live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3js-flickering-refraction-problem-s164oq?file=/src/index.js) & [full screen](https://s164oq.csb.app/) (please close the error pop-up, it's from loading GLTF) I forked a tutorial so there are other glass primitives and a control panel. If we reduce the roughness close to 0, the flickering becomes visible in the sphere primitive as well.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that worked for me was setting `.setPixelRatio(2)` to 2 or higher on my renderer. Flickering stopped and refracted objects look really good.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is a setting. Do you have `antialias` set on your renderer?

```js
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help. Someone else suggested adding `logarithmicDepthBuffer: true` but it didn't help either. I'm currently working on preparing a CodeSandbox example so others can test it.

Comment: Great, thanks. A live example is best

Comment: Edited my question and added a live example